# Should I use operator+= instead of operator+ for concatenating std::string?

Tags: c++, append, concatenation, stdstring

Is there a reason that I often see this construct:

```
std::string myString = someString + "text" + otherString + "more text";
```

... instead of this (which I very seldom see):

```
std::string myString;
myString += someString += "text" += otherString += "more text";
```

Reading the `std::string` API, it seems to me that `operator+` creates a lot of temporaries (perhaps optimized away by compiler RVO?), while the `operator+=` variant only appends text.

In some cases, the `operator+` variant will be the way to go. But when you only need to append text to an existing non-const string, why not just use `operator+=`? Any reason not to?

-Rein

Comment: Last time I measured performances, it was faster doing many `+=` than a `=` with many `+`

Comment: Do you want `otherString` and `someString` to be modified?

Comment: I don't think one form would be optimized superior to the other. We have copy elision and move semantics nowadays. @Morb When was _last time_ actually, and which optimization levels did you use?

Comment: You can always use stringstream which is both readable and efficient.

Comment: Does that second version even compile? I would expect some kind of error related to not being able to += a string onto a string literal. (EDIT: [Yup, doesn't compile.](http://ideone.com/ipgOzm))

Comment: @Morb 'last time' was half a year ago, I had something like `string something = variable1 + "text" + variable2 + "text_again" + variable3;` which I changed to something like `string something = variable1; something += "text"; something += variable2; something += "text_again"; something += variable3;`, it was done many many times. I tested it with the same data each time.

Comment: Sorry for not testing if my example compiled. My real code only has _one_ operator+= and I generalized in my head before asking the question.

Comment: From [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3ac536f5c2ef0d16) little test it looks like `+=` is twice as fast.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`operator+=` has the wrong kind of associativity for you to write code like your second example. For that to do what you want, you'd need to bracket it like so:

```
(((myString += someString) += "text") += otherString) += "more text";
```

The alternative, which gives you the readability and efficiency you want, is to use `std::stringstream`:

```
std::stringstream myString;
myString << someString << "text" << otherString << "more text";
```

Comment: Is missed that fact about the operator associativity. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

See

```
std::string aaa += bbb;
```

is similar to

```
std::string aaa = aaa + bbb;
```

so at your example will be changed *someString* and *otherString*.
In usual cases you don`t need worry about temporaries when use *operator+* - in release mode all of them will be eliminated (RVO and/or other optimization).

Comment: I don't think the optimization comment is true, the operator will still be called, it won't magically not do extra memory allocations anymore

Comment: Hmm, the all main c++ compilers used RVO optimization (you can read about it in compilers description). This optimization dependent on the compiler flags: usual it turn of in "debug" mode and turn on in "release" mode. In other case all std containers have move constructors that called when RVO couldn`t be applied. So there are will be no *extra* memory allocation.